# Trying to create first indicator. What is the error?

Tags: pine-script

Trying to create first indicator. Script is saved without showing any error but indicator does not display on screen . please help me to identify my [coding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yXYdO.jpg)the error ?

Answer (score 0):

It should be `overlay = true` not `overlay - true`

Comment: Thanks Buddy... I have done successfully.